# normal user runnig a bash script containing root command without password

Tags: permissions, root

I have a bash script that contains few commands that can only
be run by `root`, e.g. `wpa_supplicant`. I would like to allow the normal user
to run the script without sudo.

I found these posts but they are not exatcly what I want (
[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79692/running-program-as-root-without-using-sudo-with-normal-user-account),
[there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70349/running-user-script-with-root-permissions)
and [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47183/script-with-root-permission))

Comment: And what would be exactly what you want? And/or why are these solution not what you want?

Comment: Actually, [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47188/111878) to the third post you mentioned is exactly what you want.  Use `sudo`, that's what it was meant to do.  Just change the command to the one you need.

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution without sudo... but if there's none, so be it

Comment: In theory you could write a SUID program, but in practise a solution with sudo is much better. Why do you want to avoid sudo? Its call could be hidden in a separate script.